# speaker-test returns all 6 channels to front speakers

Tags: sound, kubuntu, alsa, soundcard, sound-blaster

OS: KUBUNTU 19.04
Soundcard: Creative Soundblaster ZxR
Sound Setup: front (left/right), center, bass, rear (left/right)

My problem is, that all speaker outputs are played at the front speakers.

I did the following:

- Set speaker setup at Plasma sound settings to "Analog Surround 5.1-Output + Analog Stereo-Input" (GP102 HDMI is my NVIDIA Graphics Card)
  [image]
- If I click on any rear speaker there, to test audio output, they are played on front speakers. The setup seems very faulty:

  - rear right: output on front left and right at the same time
  - rear left: output on front left and right at the same time
  - center: output on front left and right at the same time
  - front left: output on front left (one of two correct speakers)
  - front right: output on front right (one of two correct speakers)
- I then executed `alsamixer` and noticed that my NVIDIA Graphics card was initially selected. I switched with F6 to my ZxR and set it up like this:
  [image]
- I ran `speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -twav`. An error message appeared and I was unable to perform the command: Error when opening the device: -2
- I googled how to set the default device and so I did `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17
 1 [Creative       ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Creative
                      HDA Creative at 0xdf204000 irq 19
```

with `kate ~/.asoundrc` I set my default device:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.timer.card 1
```

- after a restart `speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -twav` was working: Unfortunately rear left output is on front left, rear right output is on front right, center appears to be on both front (left/right) speakers

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

---

**Update:** Most Tutorials that mess with ALSA and PULSE handle audio output via HDMI or S/PDIF. This does not apply to my setup. I plugged three 3.5mm jacks into my soundcard: (left/right), (Center/Subwoofer), (Rear left/ Rear right). This is the reason why I set my audio config to "Analog Surround 5.1-Output". Unfortunately I haven't found my case in the web nor the case where all audio outputs are played on the front speakers.

Comment: Do you have `pavucontrol` installed? If not go ahead and install that one and run it, and go the the configuration tab and make sure under profile, it is set to `Digital Surround 5.1`.

Comment: `pavucontrol` provides the same information as Pulse. Both match, that I set them to analog 5.1. I updated my initial post to make clear that I don't use S/PDIF.